# Is it possible to set 2 urls in get_absolute_url?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

I have next task and dont know how to make it.

Web page shows to user list of objects. Every object has 2 button with urls like `function_detail` and `function_change_history`. First url need open the page about details of the object and the second url need to open the page about change history. I used `get_absolute_url` to make second url but dont know how to create first url cause I need to use `get_absolute_url` again.

**models.py:**

```
@reversion.register()
class Function(models.Model):
    ***FIELDS***

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project:function_change_history', args=[self.project_id, self.code])
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^(?P<project_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<function_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/change_history/$',
        function_change_history,
        name='function_change_history'),

url(r'^(?P<project_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<function_code>[0-9a-f-]+)/detail/$',
        function_detail,
        name='function_detail'),
```

Is it possible to set `2 url` in `get_absolute_url`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why do you need them to be in get_absolute_url?

Comment: Well I use `get_absolute_url` cause I need information about specific object.

Comment: That wasn't an answer at all. Why that method, specifically? How are you using it? Why do you need two results?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the decision. For `function_detail` I use `get_absolute_url` and for `function_change_history` I use in template `{% url 'function_change_history'  project_code=project.code function_code=function.code %}`